# Nao consigo mudar o icone e o texto dentro de um Botão

Tags: javascript, html

Pessoal como eu poderia fazer um botão que mudasse de texto e ícone ao ser clicado? e clicando novamente voltaria ao botão original? poderiam me ajudar

```js
function mostrar(e) {
  if (e.classList.contains("glyphicon-plus")) { //se tem olho aberto
    e.classList.remove("glyphicon-plus"); //remove classe olho aberto
    e.classList.add("glyphicon-minus"); //coloca classe olho fechado
  } else {
    e.classList.remove("glyphicon-minus"); //remove classe olho fechado
    e.classList.add("glyphicon-plus"); //coloca classe olho aberto
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<form method="POST">
  <button type="button" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="mostrar(this)"> save </button>
</form>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Comment: Vc já está trocando os ícones, falta só trocar o texto, no **if/else** basta colocar um `e.innerText = ' Texto que quer'`

Comment: @LeAndrade pela imagem a direção do icone também esta do lado errado, na verdade se tratando de glyphicons deveria usar um subelemento `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">`, após o texto e o texto talvez dentro de um `<span>`;

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento eu ja consegui fazer irmao, unico problema é que agora nao consigo deixar o icone do lado direto, como eu poderia fazer isso?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento
<button type="button" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus" onclick="mostrar(this);incrementClick()"> Save</button>
Meu botao esta desse jeito, como q eu faço pra deixar o icone do lado direto?

Comment: Crie um elemento `<i>` com as classes `glyphicon glyphicon-plus` e no elemento `button` remova as classes `glyphicon glyphicon-plus`, o `<i>` deve ficar ao lado direito do texto e o texto preferencialmente deve ir dentro de um elemento `<span>` para que você consiga editar ele via JS sem afetar o elemento `<i>`.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento fiz aqui man, nao deu certo, tentei de varias formas ja

Answer (score -3):

Opá, eu só adicionei uma função no script. Aí vc faz as configurações para ficar no esquema

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='pt-br'>


<body>

<form>
<button type="button" class="btn glyphicon glyphicon-plus" value="MAIS" 
 onclick="mostrar(this)">
<p>MENOS</p>
</button>


</form>



<script>
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const paragraph = document.querySelector('p');

button.addEventListener('click', updateButton);

function updateButton() {
  if (button.value === 'MENOS') {
    button.value = 'MAIS';
    paragraph.textContent = 'MAIS';
  } else {
    button.value = 'MENOS';
    paragraph.textContent = 'MENOS';
  }
}

function mostrar(e) {
  if (e.classList.contains("glyphicon-plus")) { //se tem olho aberto
    e.classList.remove("glyphicon-plus"); //remove classe olho aberto
    e.classList.add("glyphicon-minus"); //coloca classe olho fechado
  } else {
    e.classList.remove("glyphicon-minus"); //remove classe olho fechado
    e.classList.add("glyphicon-plus"); //coloca classe olho aberto
  }
 }
</script>


</body>

<link rel="stylesheet"href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Eu utilizei esse site como referencia tem umas coisas legais nele: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/button

Answer (score -3):

Ao invés de usar o remove e o add, utilize o toggle, ele alterna entre ativo e desativa. É exatamente o que tu procura. No primeiro clique ativa e no segundo desativa, no terceiro ativa novamente e assim por diante.
vou deixar aqui um exemplo, essa função faz aparecer um menu, e quando apertada novamente faz ele sumir, espero que ajude.

```
function aparecerMenu(){
    const nav = document.getElementById('nav');
    nav.classList.toggle('active');
    
}
```